# How to stop visual c++ stepping into certain files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

Is there some way to filter what files Visual Studio 2005 (C++) steps into?

For example, when stepping into

```
SomeFn( a.c_str(), b.c_str(), etc );
```

I hate how it steps into the standard template library files for c_str() - instead I just want to go into SomeFn().

If there was some way to filter out any source files didn't live in the same path as the solution file that would make my life easier.

Does anyone know a way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html) article describes how to solve it for VC6, VC7 and VC8.

Comment: This was what I was looking for (took me a while to figure out the syntax, but it is working for me now)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's in VS2005 or not (I no longer have 2005 it installed on my machine), but VS2008 has a context menu item in the debugger when you right click: "Step Into Specific"

That option will let you choose which function to step into.

Comment: Nice - a way to do it on a case by case basis - works for VS2005 too

Comment: I am finding this really useful - if I had a 2nd upvote I would give it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The approach in VS9 is very similar to the VS8-approach described by Kirill. More details at [ffuts.org](http://www.ffuts.org/blog/stop-wasting-time-stepping-into-functions-you-dont/)